# Print Document to Printer using Python on Windows [WinError 1155]

Tags: python, printing

I am using the os module to try to print a document to a printer, however I am receiving a OS Error stating - [WinError 1155] No application is associated with the specified file for this operation. How can I address the error in order to print successfully?

**Below Code**

import os

os.startfile('FileName',"print")

Comment: What is it that you think `os.startfile` does?

Answer (score 0):

Give file name with this extension like .txt, or other that associate with operating system.
Only file name is not enough for printing.

os.startfile("FileName.txt", "print")

Answer (score 0):

write this

```
os.startfile("FileName.txt")
```

or "FileName.pdf". Without "print"